# c# console app in docker - check if stdin is available

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, console

All,

We have a c# dotnet core 3.0 console app (not ASP.NET) running in docker and we use the keyboard for console commands. In Docker, our app fails when it tries to read the console keyboard (stdin) as docker has redirected the input stream, and we can test for that with Console.isStdinRedirected.

However we want re-enable the console keyboard input when we are remote attaching a terminal to the app in the docker container, but that is also a redirection so isStdinRedirected doesn't help us.

Is there a way that we can test that the stdin is active so we can re-enable our keyboard? I can only think of using a try / catch around a keyboard read in a regular loop (with sleep) but that's an ugly solution.

Alternatively is there a way that docker can signal dotnet that a terminal is now attached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried a simple hello world app with console input and it worked.

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace consoleapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Enter your name: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}");
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk AS base
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

WORKDIR /app/out
CMD dotnet consoleapp.dll
```

running with -i (interactive) and -t (TTY) switches gave me the below output

```
$ docker run -it consoleapp
Enter your name: 
Zia
Hello Zia
```